# How do I "polish" a piece of equipment?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

After doing an expedition I found a relic item, and it is "rusty". I can't wear it yet as the item description says it must be polished first.

Where and how do I polish rusted equipment?

Comment: Perogies, Pączkies, Gwumpkies, Krout and Kielbasa w/ horseradish. That will polish it up real good. Duck Blood soup is good for a quick buff as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speak to the Rust Abolisher in the town of Harth. He is the one working the forge behind the Harth Chief. On the town map this area is marked as 'Antiquary'. Getting him to polish rusted items requires [Abrasives](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/item/abrasive).

I believe your best bet at getting Abrasives early on is probably doing registered guild quests (the ones that level up each time you do them) or mining in the Everwood (expeditions, registered guild quests). I don't know the drop rates yet, sorry.

The Rust Abolisher can also trade points for Relics, upgrade Relics, or forge/set decorations for your socketed equipment.

Comment: Abrasives can also be found by mining anywhere in the Everwood. I haven't found any outside of that however.

Comment: Good point, added.